# Gobblin: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.gobblin.source.extractor.extract.jdbc.MysqlSource

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, classnotfoundexception, gobblin

I am trying mysql to hdfs data ingestion using gobblin. While running mysql-to-gobblin.pull using steps below:

1) start hadoop:
`sbin\start-all.cmd`

2) start mysql service:
`sudo service mysql start`

3) set GOBBLIN_WORK_DIR:
`export GOBBLIN_WORK_DIR=/mnt/c/users/name/incubator-gobblin/GOBBLIN_WORK_DIR`

4) set GOBBLIN_JOB_CONFIG_DIR
`export GOBBLIN_JOB_CONFIG_DIR=/mnt/c/users/name/incubator-gobblin/GOBBLIN_JOB_CONFIG_DIR`

5) Start standalone
`bin/gobblin.sh service standalone start --jars /mnt/C/Users/name/incubator-gobblin/build/gobblin-sql/libs/gobblin-sql-0.15.0.jar`

gives below error

```
ERROR [JobScheduler-0] org.apache.gobblin.scheduler.JobScheduler$NonScheduledJobRunner  637 - Failed to run job GobblinMySql
org.apache.gobblin.runtime.JobException: Failed to run job GobblinMySql
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.gobblin.source.extractor.extract.jdbc.MysqlSource
```

below is the mysql-to-gobblin.pull file

```
# Job properties
job.name=GobblinMySql
job.group=MySql
job.description=Data pull from MySql

# Extract properties

extract.table.type=snapshot_only
extract.table.name=user

# Property to consider the extract as full dump
extract.is.full=true

# Source properties
# Source properties - source class to extract data from Mysql Source
source.class=org.apache.gobblin.source.extractor.extract.jdbc.MysqlSource

# Source properties
source.max.number.of.partitions=1
source.querybased.partition.interval=1
source.querybased.is.compression=true
source.querybased.watermark.type=timestamp

# Converter properties - Record from mysql source will be processed by the below series of converters
converter.classes=gobblin.converter.avro.JsonIntermediateToAvroConverter

# date columns format
converter.avro.timestamp.format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.0'
converter.avro.date.format=yyyy-MM-dd
converter.avro.time.format=HH:mm:ss

# Qualitychecker properties
qualitychecker.task.policies=gobblin.policies.count.RowCountPolicy,gobblin.policies.schema.SchemaCompatibilityPolicy
qualitychecker.task.policy.types=OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL

# Publisher properties
data.publisher.type=gobblin.publisher.BaseDataPublisher
source.querybased.schema=praveen_schema
source.entity=user
source.querybased.extract.type=snapshot

writer.builder.class=org.apache.gobblin.writer.SimpleDataWriterBuilder
writer.file.path.type=tablename
writer.destination.type=HDFS
writer.output.format=txt

data.publisher.type=org.apache.gobblin.publisher.BaseDataPublisher

mr.job.max.mappers=1

metrics.reporting.file.enabled=true
metrics.log.dir=/gobblin-kafka/metrics
metrics.reporting.file.suffix=txt

bootstrap.with.offset=earliest

fs.uri=hdfs://localhost:9000
writer.fs.uri=hdfs://localhost:9000
state.store.fs.uri=hdfs://localhost:9000

mr.job.root.dir=/gobblin-kafka/working
state.store.dir=/gobblin-kafka/state-store
task.data.root.dir=/jobs/kafkaetl/gobblin/gobblin-kafka/task-data
data.publisher.final.dir=/gobblintest/job-output
```

I am running this command from `/mnt/c/users/name/incubator-gobblin/build/gobblin-distribution/distributions/gobblin-dist` directory.

What changes I need to do here? How can i solve it?

Comment: If you found a solution yourself, please post in as an answer for the next folks that will hit the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is to add this jar or dependency to get rid of Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.gobblin.source.extractor.extract.jdbc.MysqlSource

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.linkedin.gobblin</groupId>
    <artifactId>gobblin-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

download jar from this mvn [website](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.linkedin.gobblin/gobblin-core/0.8.0).

Hope this helps.